# Using a lambda as key within builtin string sort(), hard to identify Big-O

Tags: python, big-o

The following code I made takes every string in `y` and places the anagrams together in the list:

```
>>> y = ['eat','beat','sweet','tea', 'eta', 'teews', 'leet', 'tele']
>>> y.sort(key=lambda x: sorted(x))
>>> y
['beat', 'eat', 'tea', 'eta', 'leet', 'tele', 'sweet', 'teews']
```

When trying to give a time complexity for this solution, I had a hard time. I think it is O(nlogn) but I am not sure what lambda is actually doing here.  Mainly because I am not actually sure what is going on under the hood python.

Can anyone shed some light on  the time complexity using lambda as a key within pythons string sort builtin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda function passed as argument while sorting is applied once to each element from the iterable, and used for comparaison between each others.

`y.sort(key=lambda x: sorted(x))` means that for each element `x` in your list `y`, `stored(x)` is called and will determine which string has to come first in the final list.

As sorting is indeed `O(n log n)`, and saying that your list contains `m` strings of `n` average length, I would say the complexity here is `O(m * (n log n) + (m log m))`.

Comment: Very precise time complexity, thanks a lot. Why isn't this considered to be nested? Since each sort does a sort. Are these two really two discrete steps? Couldn't this be O(m*(nlogn^(mlogm)))?

Comment: @ApathyBear I am sorry but I am not sure to fully understand. What do you mean by "each sort does a sort", as there is only one main sort which is using `n` others sorts? Are you saying that the time complexity could actually be `O(m*n*m*log(m)*log(n))`, which is bigger than the one I gave? As i said, the lambda function is applied only once, and Python store and use the result to perform the sort, so it should not be bigger than what I said.

Answer (score 3):

@Delgan has a great answer but since I'm on a lambda roll today, I'll toss in my $.02. A lambda is just an anonymous function. I rewrote yours as a regular function and included a `print` to see what the sort key looks like.

```
>>> def my_sorted_key_fctn(key):
...     sorted_key = sorted(key)
...     print(sorted_key)
...     return sorted_key
... 
>>> y = ['eat','beat','sweet','tea', 'eta', 'teews', 'leet', 'tele']
>>> y.sort(key=my_sorted_key_fctn)
['a', 'e', 't']
['a', 'b', 'e', 't']
['e', 'e', 's', 't', 'w']
['a', 'e', 't']
['a', 'e', 't']
['e', 'e', 's', 't', 'w']
['e', 'e', 'l', 't']
['e', 'e', 'l', 't']
>>> y
['beat', 'eat', 'tea', 'eta', 'leet', 'tele', 'sweet', 'teews']
>>>
```

You sorted the list by the letters of the key put in alphabetical order.

But you didn't need a lambda in this case. If all the lambda does is call a function with the same parameters as the lambda... then it didn't do anything useful at all. Just use the original function.

```
>>> y.sort(key=sorted)
>>> y
['beat', 'eat', 'tea', 'eta', 'leet', 'tele', 'sweet', 'teews']
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, wow thanks for the tip. No idea you could pass sorted() into key, but it makes complete sense.